# VBA UDF passing cell value as data type vs passing as range. Which to use

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I have a number of UDFs in which I pass arguments as value types ie Long, String, Integer etc.

Here's a snippet of one:

```
Public Function r_check(ByRef eval_cpn As String, ByRef r As String) As String

    'Declare variables
    Dim tkt As cpnNo
    Dim cpnColl As Collection
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim cpn_number As String
    
    'Assign variables
    Call FetchCpnData(tkt)
    Set cpnColl = New Collection
    
    'Start
    For i = 1 To Len(eval_cpn)
        
        'If string is a number
        cpn_number = mid(eval_cpn, i, 1)
        
        If cpn_number <> "," Then
            
            'Search through array
            For j = LBound(tkt.Cpn_nbr) To UBound(tkt.Cpn_nbr)
            
                'coupon number = number from geo col
                If tkt.Cpn_nbr(j).cpn_no_prime = cpn_number Then
                
                    'If tkt rbd = rule rbd
                    If r = tkt.Cpn_nbr(j).r Or r = vbNullString Then
                    
                        If Len(eval_cpn) = 1 Then
                            r_check = cpn_number
                            Erase tkt.Cpn_nbr
                            Exit Function
                        Else
                            cpnColl.Add cpn_number
                        End If
                        
                    End If
                
                End If
            
            Next j
        
        End If
    
    Next i
```

The UDFs work as is, however I am wondering if there are any negatives of passing cell values as data types? The function arguments are not being altered in any way.

Should I be passing cell values as a range and then assigning the cell value to a new variable?

Appreciate any input.

Comment: The _Principle of Least Knowledge_ seems to apply here: if the function needs a value, then it doesn't need to know about an object that knows what the value is - it just needs that value. Also, consider passing parameters `ByVal`.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon thanks for the reply. Are there any pros/cons of either approach?

Comment: If you ever want to invoke that function from a macro or some other VBA code, be it only to test and debug it in the _immediate pane_, it's much simpler if no `Range` gets involved.